# Cairo, get width of monospaced latin character for surface

Tags: c, cairo

I have  width & height in characters of future PNG, need draw exact fit picture.

```
int  font_height=13, font_width=?;
cairo_surface_t *surface = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24, font_width * pic_width_in_chars, font_height * pic_height_in_chars );
cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(surface);
cairo_select_font_face(cr, "Consolas", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL);
cairo_set_font_size( cr, font_height );
// fill surface by characters, no need help
```

For "Сonsolas" I picked manually proportion:
font_width = font_height * 3/5; But how to get it from API ?

Thanks, extents.x_advance is what I seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, because the width of a single glyph is dependent on which character it is. You can compute the whole width adding the width of each one or using the whole string to do so.

In case of monospaced fonts, the width of any character is equal to the width of any other character. So if you compute one, you can multiply it by the number of characters in the string.

So the short answer is

- There is no *unit* width for characters, except in monospaced fonts.

Using [`cairo_text_extents()`](https://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-text.html#cairo-text-extents) can help quickly compute the width of the string. If it's a monospaced font, just use an arbitrary character and use it as the unit width.

Comment: I use monospaced font, and I found manually proportion 3/5 for width/height of character